# Why we can't load large size file from file dialog and display data of file on textArea in qml?

Tags: python, qt, qml

I am trying to browse a file through FileDialog and display the content of file into TextArea of qml integrate with python. It works properly with small size file, but TextArea as well as app getting stuck when we browse a large size file. so, How to load large size file from FileDialog and update text of TextArea with data of file in qml?

In below code read() is a pyqt slot and jsonstring is pyqtproperty:

```
FileIO {
    id: fileIoObject
}
FileDialog {
   id: fileDialog
   visible: visible
   onAccepted: {
     setOption(DontUseNativeDialogs, true)
     console.log("Accepted: " + fileUrl)
     fileTextArea.text = fileDialog.fileUrl
     fileIoObject.source = fileUrl
     fileIoObject.read()
     }
}
TextArea {
  id: jsonTextArea
  text: fileIoObject.jsonString
}
```

.py

```
@pyqtSlot()
    def read(self):
        fileName = self.name.replace('file://', '')
        if (QFile.exists(fileName)):
            file = QFile(fileName)
            if (file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)):
                data = file.readAll()
                codec = QTextCodec.codecForUtfText(data)
                self.setJsonString(codec.toUnicode(data))
                self.jsonStringChanged.emit()
                self.prevJsonStr = self.getJsonString()
```

I expect the solution, how to load large size file from FileDialog and update text of TextArea with data of file in qml.

Comment: what is _large size file_ in your understanding? what is `fileIoObject`? please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: textfile have more lines(e.g 2 lack),fileIoObject is python class object